# Existe alguna manera de recibir en mi metodo cualquier clase como parametros c# net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Buenas pondré un ejemplo sencillo de lo que quiero hacer y ver si se puede.

Tengo 3 `class` con sus propiedades

```
class test1
{
  public int num1 = 0;
  public string cadena1 = "";

}

class test2
{
  public int num2 = 0;
  public string cadena2 = "";
  public long long2 = 0;


}
class test3
{
  public int num3 = 0;
  public bool bool= false;

}
```

ahora desde el `controller` tengo varios métodos que reciben a esas 3 `class` y mi intención es validar las propiedades de esas `class` en el metodo `validocualquierparametro`

```
    [Route("prueba/test1")]
    [HttpPost]
    public pruebatest1 (test1 test)
    {
        // aqui lo llamo con la interface
       prueba.validocualquierparametro(test)
    }

    [Route("prueba/test2")]
    [HttpPost]
    public pruebatest2 (test2 test)
    {
        // aqui lo llamo con la interface
       prueba.validocualquierparametro(test)
    }

    [Route("prueba/test3")]
    [HttpPost]
    public pruebatest3 (test3 test)
    {
        // aqui lo llamo con la interface
       prueba.validocualquierparametro(test)
    }
```

Ahora tengo mi `class` con mi metodo y una `interface` el cual recibo como parametro la `class` test1

```
public void validocualquierparametro(test1 test)// asi lo tengo
// me gustaria que el metodo pueda recibir cualquiera de las clases sin tener que agregar el metodo 3 veces con cada clase, es para simplificar el codigo
public void validocualquierparametro(como recibo aqui cualquiera de las clase test)
    {
        try
        {
            PropertyInfo[] info = typeof(test1).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo p in properties)
            {
                if (//mi condicion)
                {
                    // los valido
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           // manejo las excepciones
        }
     }

     public interface Interface
    {
        void method(test1 test);//asi lo tengo
        void method(como recibo aqui cualquiera de las clase test);
    }
```

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas en *programación genérica C#*. Curioso, en un curso que tuve primero vi programación genérica antes que interfaces, interesante

Comment: @AlfaRojo alguna idea de como poder implementarlo?

Comment: tenes que derivar test1,test2,test3 de una clase testX por ejemplo o de una interfaz y lo que recibe tu metodo es la interfaz en cuestion o la clase testX. Si me sobra un poco de tiempo posteo una respuesta si es q con esto no lo resuelves. Saludos

Comment: Ufff honestamente darte como respuesta una definición tan larga te puede aburrir, poniendolo simple con la agregación de `<T>` al lado del nombre de tu clase `public class myClass <T>{//...}`  [busca en google](https://www.netmentor.es/entrada/generics-csharp#:~:text=Conclusi%C3%B3n-,1%20%2D%20Qu%C3%A9%20son%20Generics%20en%20C%23,%E2%80%9Cseguro%E2%80%9D%20ante%20diferentes%20tipos.)

Comment: Intente hacerlo asi @Cmbuffa, pero no logre culminarlo y me daba errores

Comment: @AlfaRojo, eso de generico no lo habia visto, investigare y vere si puedo solventar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias hacer esto como menciono @AlfaRojo y tambien agregarle una condicion que la clase que pases sea de un tipo ITest de Interface por ejemplo. Esto puede ser util para evitar pasar a este metodo cualquier otra clase que no sean las 3 clases que definiste

> where T : ITest

```
        public void validocualquierparametro<T>(T test) where T : ITest
        {
            try
            {
                PropertyInfo[] info = typeof(T).GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo p in info)
                {
                if (//mi condicion)
                {
                        // los valido
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // manejo las excepciones
            }
        }
```

Tus clases quedarian asi si quieres utilizar la clausula ***where T : ITest***

```
    class test1 : ITest
    {
        public int num1 = 0;
        public string cadena1 = "";

    }

    class test2 : ITest
    {
        public int num2 = 0;
        public string cadena2 = "";
        public long long2 = 0;


    }
    class test3 : ITest
    {
        public int num3 = 0;
        public bool boolean = false;
    }

    interface ITest
    {

    }
```

lo de la interfaz es opcional tambien podrias dejarlo de esta forma sin interfaz

```
public void validocualquierparametro<T>(T test)
```

La llamada en tu controller quedaria asi, donde entre < > estas pasando el tipo especifico a tu metodo generico, es como decirle al compilador que lo que esta en T lo reemplace con lo que le pases en los < > (en este caso test3)

```
    [Route("prueba/test3")]
    [HttpPost]
    public pruebatest3 (test3 test)
    {
        // aqui lo llamo con la interface
       prueba.validocualquierparametro<test3>(test)
    }
```

Comment: Listo debo modificar unas cositas para que funcione perfecto gracias